# How to find how a package is installed on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, package-management, dpkg

I have some packages installed on my system, but I am sure I did not install the package nor anything similar that may install that package. I searched in my `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `var/log/apt/history.log` with grep and no package with that name is shown. So is there any other way to know how a package is installed?

Comment: How about `dpkg -l` or `apt-mark showmanual` ... or three dozen variations? Btw, if you want to have this sort of information it's basically too late by now. If, however, you'd store this information (package selections) in a place _like_ `/etc` and kept it under version control via `etckeeper` and regularly shipped it off to another location it would be considerably harder for someone to tamper with and you'd see how the file/package came to be installed. Also, _is_ the package even manually installed right now? `apt-mark showmanual` vs. `apt-mark showauto` could show.

Comment: Also, since there are other ways how software can generally get installed even on a Debian it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a little more circumstantial information such as the name of said package what you tried other than looking into those files (the former is log-rotated, if I am not mistaken, so either your info could linger in an older copy or could simply have been purged already).

Comment: You mention `dpkg.log`, have you checked the older files, `dpkg.log.1` etc.? (Assuming there are any...)